# RactiveJS parse error

Tags: ractivejs

I was trying to accomplish something in a template and I have noticed something very strange.

```
<div class="text-overflow">{{ replies[0].message.indexOf('/assets/uploads/') >= 0 ? 'Image file' : replies[0].message }}</div>
```

Frankly I just can't find anything wrong with this.. maybe someone can enlighten me.

Error is as following:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you've found a bug! Have opened an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/ractivejs/ractive/issues/2325

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that seems to be caused by the `replies[0]` part. If you change `0` to a string, or an expression, it works, so you can use this as a work-around:

```html
<div class="text-overflow">{{ replies[+0].message.indexOf('/assets/uploads/') >= 0 ? 'Image file' : replies[0].message }}</div>
```